# Rename Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring

Hi i have a noob question :-) I have an app in the store and the name of the app is build like this **name1.com.domain.name2**
So in my old project i have the directories (Java) name1, com, domain and name2 (4)

My new project (i want to update the old app) has only 3 directories like com.name1.domain

I tried to refactor for exampe com into name1.com but not working, any way to solve this so i can rename the package so it hat the same name as the old package?

Comment: Old app for example: app.com.myapps.app  
new app/project has only : com.myapp.apps

Comment: `Rename Android Studio Project` You better advertise for 'change package name'.

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package). I've already used this method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep for comments.

Use the shortcut key "Shift+F6" or In your Keymappings(File->Settings->Keymappings) look for the shortcut key "Rename".

Select the package name in editor window as shown below in the picture and press the "Rename" configuration key on your keyboard.[image]